How to make DataTable2 horizontally scrollable?
I'm trying to implement DataTable2 migrating from DataTable in flutter. In DataTable, it was automatically horizontally scrolling based on header/cell content, but in DataTable2 the header values get trimmed and cell values gets wrapped (overflowed).
How to make DataTable2 horizontally scrollable without trimming headers?
I also have the cell content flexible. How to make DataRow height flexible based on content height in DataTable2?


Your table needs minWidth to be scrollable, otherwise it will take the size of the parent container and will shrink instead of scroll.
To make the text of your table not overflow you can add softWrap but it won't work if your data is too long, maybe you should try to add dataRowHeight to make your rows a fixed bigger size.
...
Datatable2(
  minWidth: 800, //the smallest width your table will shrink to
  columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      label: Text('Habilidades Requeridas',
        softWrap: true),
    ),
    //more columns here
  ],
rows: _yourRows, 
),

...
